# Suck on Creating an animated email submit button

Tags: forms, animation, submit

I'm trying an email submission form to animate when its click which it does right now, but also submit the data.

So basically I need "postForm" and ".submit-email" to function simultaneously. I think I'm close, but any help would be great or if someone knows of a tutorial that shows an animation happen while the data is submitted, that would be great. Thank you in advance.

[Javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGCTT.png)

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D28J1.png)

Comment: Please post the code as text not screenshot.